# How can I make JavaScript code more "clean"

Tags: javascript

I have made this functions

```
let buttonOne = true;
    let buttonTwo = false;
    let buttonThree = false;
    let buttonFour = false;
    let buttonFive = false;

    const handleButtonOne = () => {
        buttonOne = true;
        buttonTwo = false;
        buttonThree = false;
        buttonFour = false;
        buttonFive = false;
    };

    const handleButtonTwo = () => {
        buttonTwo = true;
        buttonOne = false;
        buttonThree = false;
        buttonFour = false;
        buttonFive = false;
    };

    const handleButtonThree = () => {
        buttonTwo = false;
        buttonOne = false;
        buttonThree = true;
        buttonFour = false;
        buttonFive = false;
    };

    const handleButtonFour = () => {
        buttonTwo = false;
        buttonOne = false;
        buttonThree = false;
        buttonFour = true;
        buttonFive = false;
    };

    const handleButtonFive = () => {
        buttonTwo = false;
        buttonOne = false;
        buttonThree = false;
        buttonFour = false;
        buttonFive = true;
    };
```

This functions are to change the state of the different buttons and show different content to the user when the state of button is true. This works well, however, I thinks it's not the right way to do it.

My question is. How can I do the same with less code and more elegant way? Any tips?

Comment: First of all, use an array, instead of "numbered variable names". Second, write _one_ function that takes the numeric index of the button as parameter. Loop over the array, set true for that index, and false for all others.

Comment: if you manage to look into this kind of question, it means that your approach to the problem is clumsy. Here it must be at the interface of your buttons...

Answer (score 2):

Give each button a name or id, and have something like this, when name === the button name, it's `true`, otherwise it's `false`.

```
let currentButton = 'button1';

handleButtonClick(name) {
    currentButton = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

```js
let buttons = {
  one: true,
  two: false,
  three: false,
  four: false,
  five: false
}
let trueButton = "one"

const handleButton = (key /* eg. "one"*/) => {
    buttons[trueButton] = false
    buttons[key] = true
    trueButton = key
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have 1 item to be true, then it will be easier you put it in paremeter of the function

```js
let num = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

function create(trueindex) {
  for (let i in num) {
    if (i == num[trueindex]) {
      window[`button${num[i]}`] = true
    } else {
      window[`button${num[i]}`] = false
    }
  }
}
create(1)
console.log(buttonOne)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one button with `true` as value, you could store only the number of the button, which is set (to `true`).

For switching some indicators iterate the coutn of buttons and set the one which matches to the wanted style and all other to a differen unselected style.

```js
function setButton(event) {
    const targetElement = event.target;
    button = +targetElement.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    document.getElementById(`button${i}`).style.backgroundColor = i === button
        ? '#ff7070'
        : '#dddddd'
}

let button = undefined;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    document.getElementById(`button${i}`).addEventListener('click', setButton, false);
```

```html
<button id="button0" value="0">one</button>
<button id="button1" value="1">two</button>
<button id="button2" value="2">three</button>
<button id="button3" value="3">four</button>
<button id="button4" value="4">five</button>
```